# Excel 2007 comment display bug with freezepanes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

If I have a multi-line comment in a cell above the freezepanes row, and scroll down a couple of rows, the comment is cut off at the freezepanes point.  I'm seeing this behavior in Excel 2007, and don't recall that it was a problem in Excel 2003.  The entire comment should appear when you hover over the cell, and that has nothing to do with the placement of the cell relative to the freezepanes row or column.  Is there a workaround?  And can someone confirm whether it's fixed in Excel 2010?

Comment: Excel 2010 has the same behaviour as 2007. I'm not awware of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This will occur whenever the comment size is larger than the frozen pane.

A workaround is to increase the row heights of the frozen rows such that the entire comment fits. It will then be fully visible within the frozen pane.

Comment: This won't work in my case since the comment contains a variable number of lines, and making the frozen heading as high as the maximum comment would leave no room for data.  I consider this a regression error since it worked in Excel 2003.